# PHP gallery album

Tags: php

i am writing a php script that retrieves images from a database and shows them on page inside an album , each album contains several images...

here is an example for the code below :

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album where status='process' ORDER BY albumid DESC  LIMIT $start_from, 12";`

```
<?php

$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) 
{
  $aid=$row['albumid'];
  $aimage=$row['image'];
  $aname=$row['name'];
  $astatus=$row['status'];

  echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 agile_gallery_grid">';
  echo '<div class="hover ehover14">';

  ?>
  <?php
  echo"<a href='#details?d=$aid' onclick='showfunction()'>";        
  echo "<img src='admin/acatch/$aimage' class='img-responsive' alt='$aname' width='200' height='200' data-picture_id='$aid'>";
  echo'</a>';
}
?>
```

this code shows all the albums contained in the database ,
but what i want to do is that when i click on the album cover , i want to display the images inside it on the same page , but i am not able to pass the album id to another php script on the same page to do this,
please if anyone can help
thank u in advance

Comment: How is your table structure for the images? Do you have a table for albums, and another for images that have a relation-column to the albums? If so, you could use a sql ‘JOIN’-statement. And pass them to the album function.

Comment: yes but how ?can you please post an example of a written code ?

Comment: Here is a sql example for joining tbl_album, and a fictional tbl_images: $sql = “SELECT a.columns_names FROM tbl_album a JOIN tbl_images i ON a.id = i.album_id where a.status='process' ORDER BY a.albumid DESC LIMIT $start_from, 12”

Comment: and by this way how can i show the content of the album on the same page ?

Comment: i mean how to give that album id to another div that contains another SQL on the same page

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following code:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album where status='process' ORDER BY albumid DESC  LIMIT $start_from, 12";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)):
    $aid=$row['albumid']; 
    $aimage=$row['image']; 
    $aname=$row['name']; 
    $astatus=$row['status'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 agile_gallery_grid">
        <div class="hover ehover14">
            <a href='#details?d=$aid' onclick='showfunction()'>
                <img src="admin/acatch/<?=$aimage?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?=$aname?>" width="200" height="200" data-picture_id="<?=$aid?>">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_album" id="gallery_album_<?=$row['albumid']?>">
    <?php 
        /**
         *  now collect all images associated with each album by using $aid
         */
        $sql_images = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album_images WHERE fk_album_id = $aid";
        $images_result = mysql_query($sql_images, $con);
        while($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($images_result)):  
            ?>
            <div class="gallery_album_image"><img src="<?=$image['dir_and_filename']?>"></div>
            <?php 
        endwhile; 
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What we are doing here is gettign all the albums as you allready does. But we introduce a subquery inside the first `while`-loop to fetch all associated images for each album.
We put these images inside new `div`-container with a unique album id you can use to show or hide the actual album with your `showfunction()`
Use CSS and javascript to show or hide accordingly.

**OBS! WARNING!!** Your mysql queries, and the one I provided, is very very BAD!
Have a look into prepared statement using php `PDO` or `mysqli`...